# DCC GARCH: How to export residual values using Stata?

Tags: stata

I run bivariate DCC GARCH(1,1) in Stata.

```
mgarch dcc (x y =, noconstant) , arch(1) garch(1)
```

How can I export the value of the residuals (for both variables)?

Comment: This question seems to be more appropriate for Stack Overflow since it is about using Stata.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to export to a MS Excel file. Below an example:

```
clear all
set more off

webuse stocks

mgarch dcc (toyota nissan honda = L.toyota L.nissan L.honda, noconstant), arch(1) garch(1)

* compute residuals and export to MS Excel
predict double resid, residuals
export excel using residuals.xls
```

There are other ways to export data. Take a look at `help export`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you meant 'how do I get both residuals from this DCC-GARCH) then simply:

predict resid1 resid2, residuals